# How to find unanswered questions with two specific tags, or sort them by the OP's reputation?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, search, sorting

1. Is there a way to get all the questions which are unanswered and matching two or more tags?
   For example, I want to get all the unanswered questions with the [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) tags.
2. Is there a way to sort questions in a particular tag based on the rating of the person who asked the questions?

I was browsing through Stack Overflow, and the two features described above will be helpful to me.

Comment: 1. Probably, did you search here on Meta for older questions on the subject? 2. No. It should not matter what the question asker rep is.

Comment: i was searching like java,regex but could not get the expected result. I assumed that could be an enhancement and did not check before posting

Comment: I was not looking for a specific problem, i was searching common issues that devloper may face And always I can learn more from trusted user questions

Comment: New people can ask excellent questions too; look for questions with positive score (sort by votes) instead.

Comment: thanks,i have done that already, sort by rating may may expose new set of questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+regex?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50).  Just put the two tags you want into the search tab, in this case "[java] [regex]" and select the "unanswered" tab.
2. No.